# In this SML code I'm trying to open a file selected by the user but I keep getting a tycon mismatch error

Tags: sml

I am working on a Standard ML (SML) program that reads a file given by the user and prints the first line of the file. I have written the following code:

```
fun readAndPrintLine instream =
    case TextIO.inputLine instream of
        NONE => (TextIO.closeIn instream; print "End of file.\n")
      | SOME text => (TextIO.closeIn instream; print ("Read line: " ^ text ^ "\n"))

 (* -->I believe the tycon mismatch is in the openAndHandleFile function here: *)

fun openAndHandleFile fileName =  (*I believe the problem lies in this block of code*)
    case TextIO.openIn fileName of
        NONE => print ("Error: Failed to open the file " ^ fileName ^ ".\n")
      | SOME instream => readAndPrintLine instream

fun read_file () = let
    val _ = print "Please enter a filename to be parsed: \n"
    val fileNameOpt = TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn
in
    case fileNameOpt of
        NONE => print "No filename provided.\n"
      | SOME fileName => openAndHandleFile fileName
end

(* Call the read_file function to start the program *)
val _ = read_file ();
```

However when I try to run the following code I get the following error:

```
testing4.sml:7.5-9.51 Error: case object and rules do not agree [tycon mismatch]
  rule domain: TextIO.instream option
  object: TextIO.instream
  in expression:
    (case (TextIO.openIn fileName)
    of NONE => print ("Error: Failed to open the file " ^ fileName ^ ".\n")
     | SOME instream => readAndPrintLine instream)
val it = () : unit

I am new to SML and I know it can be strict about data types, but I'm not sure where the issue is. I think the problem lies in the "openAndHandleFile" function.
```

What am I doing wrong in my code, and how can I fix the tycon mismatch error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`TextIO.openIn`](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Eappel/smlnj/basis/text-io.html#SIG:TEXT_IO.openIn:VAL) does not return an option type, so you can't match on the `SOME` or `NONE` constructors. If `TextIO.openIn` fails, it instead raises an [`Io` exception](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Eappel/smlnj/basis/io.html#SIG:IO.Io:EXN:SPEC).

You would want to handle this exception to address the case where the file cannot be opened.

```
readAndPrintLine (TextIO.openIn fileName) 
handle ... => print "No filename provided.\n"
```